# OCaml: type inference with polymorphic variants

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

Function `f` argument type is `[< 'A | 'B]` that's what I want.

```
# let rec f = function
  | `A -> 0
  | `B -> let _ = f in 1
;;
val f : [< `A | `B ] -> int = <fun>
```

However, if I call it recursively with `'A` it infers an undesired for me type `[< 'A | 'B > 'A]` which requires at least `'A`:

```
# let rec f = function
  | `A -> 0
  | `B -> let _ = f `A in 1
;;
val f : [< `A | `B > `A ] -> int = <fun>
```

I still need to recursively call `f 'A`, but how do I keep the type `[< 'A | 'B]`?

Comment: Why is this type an issue ?

Comment: @Drup I want to pass values of type `['B]` to `f`. I know I can pass values of type `[> 'B]` but that would relax static typing guarantees of my other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is yet another instantiation of the `let`-polymorphism constraints, that hinders the usage of polymorphic recursive function. Since, OCaml 3.12 we have an [explicit way](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.02/extn.html#sec227) to declare that your function is polymorphic.

Your case is a little bit more complex, since you have implicit type variable, that occurs inside the row-polymorphic type. Maybe there is a better way, but my approach is to make this type variable explicit, with the following type definition

```
type 'a t = 'a constraint 'a = [< `A | `B]
```

With such handy type, it is easy to write a proper annotation for a function:

```
let rec f : 'a . 'a t -> int = function
| `A -> 0
| `B -> let _ = f `A  in 1
```

Just in case, if you don't want to expose this `'a t`, that's ok, since you're not required, `'a t` is equal to `[< 'A | 'B]` it just makes `'a` type variable explicit:

```
module M : sig
  val f : [< `A | `B] -> int
  end = struct
let rec f : 'a . 'a t -> int = function
  | `A -> 0
  | `B -> let _ = f `A  in 1
end;;
```

Without introducing `'a t` type, you can make it with a little bit uglier (but this is of course a matter of taste) notation:

```
let rec f : 'a . ([< `A | `B] as 'a) -> int = function
  | `A -> 0
  | `B -> let _ = f `A  in 1
```

Of course, this will not scale, for non trivial types.